# File output to terminal

Tags: python, sqlite

Working in python, and databases in a class, my teacher told me to write the commands I would usually do in terminal using sqlite3 in a file, and then he outputted it to the terminal with a command that used the "<" symbol.

The file content is basically this

```
CREATE TABLE palavras(
count INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
palavra TEXT,
silaba1 TEXT,
silaba2 TEXT,
silaba3 TEXT,
silaba4 TEXT,
silaba5 TEXT,
silaba6 TEXT,
silaba7 TEXT,
silaba8 TEXT,
silaba9 TEXT,
silaba10 TEXT,
silaba11 TEXT,
silaba12 TEXT,
silaba13 TEXT,
silaba14 TEXT,
silaba15 TEXT,
silaba16 TEXT,
silaba17 TEXT,
silaba18 TEXT,
silaba19 TEXT,
silaba20 TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE silabas(
silaba_fonetica TEXT,
som TEXT
);
```

Can anyone tell me how he did it?

Comment: `print open("somefile.txt").read()`?

Answer (score 1):

Just load your db file with sqlite3 then pipe in the file containing the sql commands :

```
sqlite3 file.db < file.sql
```